# Как настроить статику в Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

По адресу `/var/www/jabber/scripts` есть файл `index.html`.

В папке `/var/www/jabber` находится c# приложение (консольное). Пробую настроить nginx, но при заходе по ссылке `xxx.ru/scripts/index.html` пишет `ошибка 404`

```
server {
    listen 443   ssl;
    server_name  xxx.ru;
    root /var/www/jabber;


    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /var/www/ssl/1_xxx_ru_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/ssl/2_xxx_ru.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;



    location / {
            autoindex  on;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }

    location /scripts {
       root /var/www/jabber/scripts;
       index  index.html index.htm;
      }
}
```

Вроде настроил путь к папке scripts, но показывает ошибку 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
server {
    listen 443   ssl;
    server_name  xxx.ru;

    root /var/www/jabber;
    index  index.html index.htm;    

    ssl_certificate      /var/www/ssl/1_xxx_ru_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/ssl/2_xxx_ru.key; 

    location / {
            autoindex  on;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }    
    location /scripts/ {
       try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Я убрал некоторые ssl-настройки, которые в современных реалиях скорее вредны, чем полезны.

Answer (score 3):

при такой конфигурации, как у вас:

```
location /scripts {
   root /var/www/jabber/scripts;
   index  index.html index.htm;
  }
```

при запросе к `xxx.ru/scripts/index.html` *nginx* будет пытаться отобразить файл `/var/www/jabber/scripts/scripts/index.html`, а не `/var/www/jabber/scripts/index.html`, как вам требуется.